# Solr 4.1 range filter query does not work in a specific scenario

Tags: solr

Some weird behavior with solr range query:

When my primary_longitude range's lower limit is less than -100, then solr does not return any result, eventhough the data is present.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/<CORE>/select/?qt=dismax&q=Y&qf=show_all_flag&fl=*&fq=primary_longitude%3A%5B-97.500+TO+-101.999%5D&rows=25&start=0&sort=available_y+desc%2C+net_score+desc&wt=json&debugQuery=true
```

The query below should return a subset of data that is returned by the above query, so i know there is data that matches the query.

WORKS:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/<CORE>/select/?qt=dismax&q=Y&qf=show_all_flag&fl=*&fq=primary_longitude%3A%5B-97.500+TO+-99.999%5D&rows=25&start=0&sort=available_y+desc%2C+net_score+desc&wt=json&debugQuery=true
```

Any ideas? I tried reversing the order of the numbers in query 1 and that returned results that were not in that range.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can check for :-

1. The primary_`longitude` field is defined as `tdouble` with proper precision for treating it as a number and not as a `text` values. (Need to see your schema.xml)
2. The Negative numbers should probably be reversed from lower to higher `[-101.999 TO -97.500]`